# Comparing with getClass() when the other item is of a primative datatype

Tags: java

Is it possible to do something like the following

```
for (int i = 0; i < chararray.length; i++) {
    Character myChar = new Character (chararray[i]);

    if (myChar.getClass() == char) {
        body of method;
    }
}
```

Basically I want to test whether the value stored at position `i` of `chararray` is of a certain datatype eg. is it A-Z or a number 1-100. Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of chararray? How is it declared?

Comment: A-Z and 1-100 aren't 'datatypes'. They are value ranges. Your question doesn't make sense as posed.

Answer (score 1):

If all you are trying to do is check if a character is a letter or a digit, you can do it this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < chararray.length; i++) {
    if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(chararray[i])) {
        // this character is a letter or a digit
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test if a class is a certain primitive class you should do it this way

```
Class cls = ...
if (cls == char.class) {
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the class of a primitive with `char.class`, `int.class` etc.

That said, I can tell you that one of two things is true:

- if `chararray` is a `char[]`, then *every* element in it will be of type `char` (never `Character`). A `char[]` can only hold `char` primitives.
- if `chararray` is an array of reference types that might hold `Character` objects (`Object[]`, `Character[]`, `T[]` etc), then the element will *never* be a `char`, since a primitive type can't be stored in an array of reference types.

In the latter case, depending on how the array is typed, you may or may not need to do a check. If it's a `Character[]`, only `Character`s can be in it (well, or anything that's a subclass of `Character`, which is nothing since `Character` is a final class). Similarly, if it's `Integer`, it'll only contain `Integer`s. If it's `Object`, it can hold any reference type, and you'll need to do a reflection check or come up with a different design.

Boxing and autoboxing can hide the distinction between reference types and primitive types, but they are indeed different, and neither is a subtype (or assignable to, except via autoboxing/unboxing) the other.

Answer (score -1):

A char is encoded in two bytes. It can have values from 0-65535. These values can be interpreted as Unicode. But it is on you to decide if you need the numbers are the Unicode interpretation of it. You can not find out which way it should be interpreted as it is the programmer how decides what the values stand for.
You want to do something which is not necessary. You can choose yourself for what the `char` stands for.

Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/charintro.html

Assuming `ch` is of type `char`.
If you want to find out if the Unicode interpretation is actually a Letter you can use this: `Character.isLetter(ch)`

If you want to check if it is a Digit use:
    `Character.isDigit(ch)`

Comment: Err, no. A char is 2 bytes.

Comment: Shure, my mistake, correted it.

Comment: You corrected part of it but the major errors remain. It can have values from `0..65535.` They are not ASCII, they are Unicode.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use .instanceOf() method to check object type.

Comment: There is no `.instanceOf()` method in Java.